# Alamofire API(Digest Access Authentication) data access error

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, digest-authentication

I tried Alamofire to communicate with my server API to get the JSON data.
My API uses Digest Access Authentication, but I had problems in facing the server Challenges initially and managed to overcome with below code.

```
    let userNameValue = "username"
    let passwordValue = "password"
    let credential = URLCredential(user: userNameValue, password: passwordValue, persistence: .forSession)        
    let sessionMananager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    let request = sessionMananager.request("http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(userNameValue)/\(passwordValue)")
        .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result
    }
```

**The Output looked like**

```
    Response:   
     { Status Code: 500, Headers {
           Connection =     (
               close
           );  
           "Content-Length" =     (
                0
           );
           "Content-Type" =     (
                "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
           );
     } }
    Result: FAILURE
```

After some search I changed .responseJSON to .responseString and the output changed as below

```
    Response:   
     { Status Code: 500, Headers {
           Connection =     (
               close
           );  
           "Content-Length" =     (
                0
           );
           "Content-Type" =     (
                "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
           );  
     } }
    Result: SUCCESS
```

To make sure the challenge is handled I gave a wrong password and tried with .responseString, it gave the output with Status Code: 401.

**Suggestions Needed**

To get the data from API,

Even if Status Code: 500 is an internal error, I don't think it is the problem of server.

Comment: Strange that your code says "basic-auth" and you're talking about Digest auth. Can you check that ?

Answer (score 0):

I did so like this:

```
let sessionMananager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    let credential = URLCredential(user: "bruce", password: "dickinson", persistence: .forSession)

    sessionMananager.request("https://httpbin.org/digest-auth/undefined/bruce/dickinson")
        .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print("Result: \(String(describing: response.response?.statusCode))")
            print(response.result)
            print(response.description)
    }
```